# Accessing table cell data within list items with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html-table, innerhtml, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I'm creating a list dynamically and I need to be able to retrieve values from the table cells. The structure is:

```
<ul id="tester">
<li><div><table><tr><td></td><td id="samecellid">I WANT THIS TD VALUE..
<li><div><table><tr><td></td><td id="samecellid">I WANT THIS TD VALUE..
<li><div><table><tr><td></td><td id="samecellid">I WANT THIS TD VALUE..
```

Each list item has a table within it - this table only has one row, so the td id is unique within each list item but not within the list as a whole obviously.

The problem I have is I can't seem to get the value of the td cell. I have tried several ways, this is my latest and it doesn't work:

```
if (lengthoflist > 0) {    
    for (i=1; i<=lengthoflist; i++){    

    var ul = document.getElementById("tester");
    var mya = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[i];                     
    var myb = mya.getElementsByTagName("div");      
    var myc = myb.getElementsByTagName("table");
    var myd = myc.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var mye = myd.getElementById("samecellid");

    var celldata = mye.innerHTML;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieve the li tags in your loop, then get the last td in each li. I modified your posted code a bit. You started your loop at 1, which means that you wouldn't retrieve the first list item. Arrays are 0 indexed, so start at 0. In length of list you used `<=` which would include a nonexistent element at the end of the list.

```
var liTags = document.getElementById("tester").getElementsByTagName('li'); 

for (var i = 0; i < liTags.length; i++) {
    var tdTags = liTags[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    var celldata = tdTags[tdTags.length - 1].innerHTML; //last td
    console.log(celldata);
}
```

Update:

Here is a slightly more efficient method.

```
var liTags = document.getElementById("tester").getElementsByTagName('li'); 

for (var i = 0; i < liTags.length; i++) {
    var celldata = liTags[i].getElementsByTagName('tr')[0].lastChild.innerHTML;  //last td
    console.log(celldata);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. The For Loop is actually looping through the list so I'll try with moving your var liTags up to before the For statement.

Comment: @TW - I see. I updated my answer to reflect how I would do this.

Comment: Thats just what i'd ended up with. This is great thanks and solved this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByTagName` returns an array so it's better like that:

```
if (lengthoflist > 0) {  
    var ul = document.getElementById("tester");

    for (i=1; i<=lengthoflist; i++) {    

        var mya = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[i];                     
        var myb = mya.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];      
        var myc = myb.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
        var myd = myc.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
        var mye = myd.getElementsByTagName("td")[1]; // the second

        var celldata = mye.innerHTML;
    }
}
```

But of course with a unique ID on td tags you can get it straight.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have moved my ul up. Unfortuantely I can't have unique ids for the td elements as the list is dynamically created and I would have no way of knowing what the ids were when I came back to refer to them.

Comment: this is not referencing the ids, but the index in the collection. It says pick td number 2 -> 
<tr>
<td></td>
<td id="samecellid">I WANT THIS TD VALUE..

Answer (score 0):

If you used unique IDs you can get them directly without going down the HTML tree:

```
var mye = myd.getElementById("samecellid");
var myeA = myd.getElementById("samecellidA");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this.

```
<ul id="tester">
<li><div><table><tr><td></td><td id="samecellid1">I WANT THIS TD VALUE..
<li><div><table><tr><td></td><td id="samecellid2">I WANT THIS TD VALUE..
<li><div><table><tr><td></td><td id="samecellid3">I WANT THIS TD VALUE..

if (lengthoflist > 0) {    
    for (i=1; i<=lengthoflist; i++){
      var mye = document.getElementById("samecellid" + i);

      var celldata = mye.innerHTML;
  }
}
```

Comment: This would eb a good solution but I can't have unique ids for the td elements as the list is dynamically created and I would have no way of knowing what the ids were when I came back to refer to them.